# Yii2: how to format a value in ActiveField?

Tags: php, yii2

On my form I have this:

```php
echo $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput();
```

If the value coming from the database is `42.5` I want to have it formatted with two decimals in the input field like this `42.50`. How do I do that?

I don't find any info about formatting in [ActiveField](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html) docs...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use formatter functionalities

```
$form->field($model, 'amount', 
     ['inputOptions' => ['value' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($model->amount)]])
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the @scaisEdge answer, you can also override/modify the value in the ActiveField renderer.

Here's an example for an `ActiveField::textInput()`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'vat_rate')
    ->textInput([
        'maxlength' => true,
        'placeholder' => '0.00',
        'value' => (float) $model->vat_rate * 100,
    ]) ?>
```